# How can I place my logo at the center of my navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to put my logo in the center of my navbar, how do I do that?

I am using Bootstrap 4 Utilities, so I have tried `mx-auto` but it didn't seem to work.

So I'm assuming there are some flexbox related properties to set up, but I have no idea which one to use since I think my code is very messy.

I mean, this ain't the right way to make a navbar, but I'm doing it this way to make it easier responsive, even though I have to set it up better.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html,
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #191919;
  height: 110vh;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  max-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: start;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #191919;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #191919 !important;
}

.nav .dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #191919;
}

.nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nav .dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #191919;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #191919;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.034);
  color: #191919;
}

.nav .account {
  color: #191919;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="topnav">
  <a href="/">
    <img src="https://nosfera.app/assets/img/logo.png" id="logo" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/feed">Feed</a>
  <a href="/discover">Discover</a>
  <a href="/messages">Messages</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Account</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/profile">My profile</a>
      <a href="/projects">My projects</a>
      <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
      <a href="/help">Help</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="/login" class="account" alt="Log in">Log in (or <strong>sign up</strong>)</a>
  <a href="/logout" class="account" alt="Log out">Log out</a>
</div>
```

Excuse my english by the way.

Comment: if the logo is center, what is the position of navbar's text like 'home','feed','discover'. Would you like to provide an image which can show what is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, wrap those three sections as menus, logo and login-login out. then to nav element change justify-items to space-between. Move your logo section as second section.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html,
body {
  background: #fff;
  color: #191919;
  height: 110vh;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}

#logo {
  max-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #191919;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 18px 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: #191919 !important;
}

.nav .dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #191919;
}

.nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nav .dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #191919;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav .dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #191919;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.034);
  color: #191919;
}

.nav .account {
  color: #191919;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="topnav">
<div>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
  <a href="/feed">Feed</a>
  <a href="/discover">Discover</a>
  <a href="/messages">Messages</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Account</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="/profile">My profile</a>
      <a href="/projects">My projects</a>
      <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
      <a href="/help">Help</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="/">
    <img src="https://nosfera.app/assets/img/logo.png" id="logo" alt="">
  </a>
  </div>
  <div>
  <a href="/login" class="account" alt="Log in">Log in (or <strong>sign up</strong>)</a>
  <a href="/logout" class="account" alt="Log out">Log out</a>
    <div>
</div>
```